# Count between dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table in MySQL 5.6

| Name | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 2021-03-20 | 2021-03-21 |
| Second | 2021-03-20 | 2021-03-23 |
| Third | 2021-03-20 | 2021-03-20 |

I need a query in MYSQL to output the count of 'Name' which was alive on each day (between StartDate  & EndDate) for a given date range. Is this possible via SQL?

Output: Say we give range as 2021-03-20 and 2021-03-23

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-20 | 3 |
| 2021-03-21 | 2 |
| 2021-03-22 | 1 |
| 2021-03-23 | 1 |

Comment: MySQL version??

Comment: @SalmanA MySQL 5.6

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Then you need a calendar table... or build a list of dates through PHP or sometjing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to start with a row for each day and then use a corrected subquery.  Let me assume you have a calendar table:

```
select c.date,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where c.date between t.startdate and t.enddate
       ) as num_active
from calendar c
where c.date >= '2021-03-20' and c.date3 <= '2021-03-23';
```

If you don't have a calendar table, you can construct one on the fly for the query -- assuming you have a table with enough rows.  For instance:

```
select c.date,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where c.date between t.startdate and t.enddate
       ) as num_active
from (select date( '2021-03-20' + interval (@rn := @rn + 1) day) as date
      from t cross join
           (select @rn := -1) params
     ) c
where c.date >= '2021-03-20' and c.date3 <= '2021-03-23';
```

You can really use any table for the `c` subquery -- so long as it has enough rows.  If you know you want exactly four dates, you can hardcode those values:

```
select c.date,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where c.date between t.startdate and t.enddate
       ) as num_active
from (select date( '2021-03-20' ) as date union all
      select date( '2021-03-21' ) as date union all
      select date( '2021-03-22' ) as date union all
      select date( '2021-03-23' ) as date
     ) c
where c.date >= '2021-03-20' and c.date3 <= '2021-03-23';
```

Comment: Thank you! Was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with dates and not datetimes this should work. Basically what you are doing is creating a table of dates in the requested range and then for each of those dates you make a cartesian pair with dates of the data you have. In the end you simply count the amount of pairs bounded to each date.

```
--The data table 
DECLARE @dataTable TABLE (Name nvarchar(100), StartDate date, EndDate date)
INSERT INTO @dataTable VALUES('First', '2021-03-20', '2021-03-21')
INSERT INTO @dataTable VALUES('Second', '2021-03-20', '2021-03-23')
INSERT INTO @dataTable VALUES('Third', '2021-03-20', '2021-03-20')
--end

--Create a temporary table with dates in range
DECLARE @dates TABLE(dt date)    
DECLARE @dateFrom date
DECLARE @dateTo date

SET @dateFrom = '2021/03/01'
SET @dateTo = '2021/03/31'

WHILE(@dateFrom < @dateTo)
BEGIN
   SELECT @dateFrom = DATEADD(day, 1,@dateFrom)
   INSERT INTO @dates 
   SELECT @dateFrom
END
--end

--Do the thing
SELECT dt as Date, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM @dates
    inner join @dataTable ON dt >= StartDate and dt <= EndDate
GROUP BY dt
--end
```

Comment: Your code is SQL Server-specific and cannot be used in MySQL.

Comment: @Akina Could you explain why please.

Comment: o_O You don't know that SQL Server (aka MS SQL) and MySQL are two different servers? with their own syntax specificities which are not compatible in most cases? In this particular case - MySQL does not support anonymous code blocks primarily.

Comment: hmmm I see. I just assumed they are the same, will keep in mind for the future.